# D3.js: After setting xAxis labels text-orientation vertical, how to make sure all the texts are placed below the horizontal line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

After setting the texts of labels in vertical direction, the texts are not placed below the horizontal line which makes it look bad.

What I want is to make all the texts below the line.

I tried to modify text style, set verticla-align to text-top, but nothing changed.

Demo code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.axisX text{
            text-orientation: upright;
            writing-mode: vertical-rl;
            vertical-align:text-top;
       } 
</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>

<script>
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 20},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var names=["name1","nm2","name3","zzzzzzzzzz"]

// Create scale
var scale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);
scale.domain([0,1,2,3]);

// Add scales to axis
var x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d){
    return names[d];
  });

//Append group and insert axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .attr("class","axisX")
  .call(x_axis);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

See in fiddle:[fiddle file](https://jsfiddle.net/14ym74md/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-anchor: start;` to your CSS.

```
.axisX text {
  text-orientation: upright;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  text-anchor: start;
}
```